# Can you combine runes?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have salvaged quite a few items to extract "precious" minor runes. Sadly my bank has become quite cluttered with runes now. Is there a way to combine say 3 of the same rune to get the next level? Or can I put 4 into the mystic forge and get a new possibly higher teir rune?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like you need a Horadric Cube! While there isn't any direct upgrade path, if you place four runes into the mystic forge, you will indeed get a random higher level rune out of it.

Comment: Is it bad that I read my answer in Deckard Cain's voice?

Comment: Stay awhile and listen

Comment: Oh, no, all my thoughts are going to be in his voice now... Actually, I guess that's not such a bad thing.

Comment: Here, let me help with that: "Good news everyone!"

Comment: Oh, great. Farnsworth! Deckard! Out of my head! Shoo! Deckard, you can stay in my GPS.

Comment: Woop woop woop woop woop woop woop woop

Comment: I don't believe that the rune is guaranteed to be a higher level, it just has a chance of being higher.

Comment: @Lawton - I haven't actually tried this with runes, but whenever I use weapons/armor in the forge, I get a higher level item.